# Trying to include a file in subdirectory with codeblocks

Tags: c++, include, codeblocks

I am trying to `#include "physics/everything.hpp"` in one of my project files, however I get the error: "No such file or directory"

I am using codeblocks, and that directory definitely exists, because it is shown in the left hand project browser pane.

Any ideas?

Comment: The folder where `physics` exists (i.e.  the `/path/to/folder` part of `/path/to/folder/physics`) must be part the INCLUDE path or passed as a `-I` option to your compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Settings -> Compiler & Debugger Settings -> Search Directories` to add root of your project to include dirs. You should do it to be able to include files not by relative paths but by relative to project root.

Answer (score -2):

Apologies everyone: I should have done this:

`#include "./../physics/everything.hpp"`

The file doing the including was in a sub-directory itself... (Rookie error)

Comment: This doesn’t look healthy … configure your compiler / IDE properly instead, and use simpler include paths. As it stands, this code cannot be compiled anywhere else, it’s very fragile and bound to your specific current folder structure.

Comment: yep @KonradRudolph is right, relative paths a sucks. You making file depend on its position in project tree

Comment: Not true, the contents of these directories will never change except for code updates. The directory itself will never be moved. Apart from anything else I will never be releasing the source as this is an experimental project for my own use.

As it stands, this is a solution to the problem I had. Regardless of your opinion on whether it is a good one.

Comment: Konrads solution requires anyone else doing the compiling to have codeblocks, which is laughable really.

Comment: @Edward With all due respect, but that’s nonsense. In fact, **every** large-ish project contains a configuration of some kind. And no, that does *not* mean that everybody needs to use the same IDE – but some common basis in tools is required, true. That’s why common tools exist – such as Makefiles. It’s not merely our “opinion” that this is bad – it’s an established, unanimous consensus among experts, stemming from experience collected in decades of software engineering.

Comment: Well mine does not, so guess you're preaching to the wrong person.

Comment: @Konrad I've used Edward's construct at times. If you're coding a library which is dependent on various other third party libraries, it's nice to be able to distribute a single package whereby your user only has to include your headers. E.g. you're writing library Bar which depends on Foo0 ... Foo99 - do you really want your user to have to inform his compiler where to find 100 different library headers? What if Bar changes it's dependencies? Bar's users will have to reconfigure everything. Perhaps there is some other solution to this I'm unaware of, but relative paths has worked well for me.

Comment: @JBentley That’s a strawman. You can achieve this very well with sane include paths. I do agree that *inside* a library it doesn’t terribly matter but even then it’s conventional to use rooted include paths without going up levels, and configuring the include search path of the compiler. I.e. inside a project such as Boost, sub-projects will not `#include "../config.hpp"`, they will `#include <boost/config.hpp>`.